# Show post is custom order in frontend when load more is enabled

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-plugin-creation

I am creating a plugin to show posts in custom order it is showing ok in backend but on frontend i am using load more to show posts in categories so when i am doing this the load more does not allow to show post in custom order

`function custom_order_posts($query) {
if (is_category() && $query->is_main_query()) {

```
    $category_id = get_queried_object_id(); 
    global $wpdb;
    $custom_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'post_reorder';
    $custom_post_ids = $wpdb->get_col(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT `post_id` FROM $custom_table WHERE `category_id` = %d ORDER BY `order` ASC;",
            $category_id
        )
    );
    
    if (!empty($custom_post_ids)) {
        $query->set('post__in', $custom_post_ids);
       
        $remaining_post_ids = get_posts(array(
            'cat' => $category_id,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => array('publish', 'draft'),
            'post__not_in' => $custom_post_ids,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'fields' => 'ids',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ));
        if (!empty($remaining_post_ids)) {
            $query->set('post__in', array_merge($custom_post_ids, $remaining_post_ids));
            $query->set('orderby', 'post__in');
        } else {
            $query->set('post__in', $custom_post_ids);
            $query->set('orderby', 'post__in');
        }
    }
}
```

}`

This function works really well when the pagination for category is on but on load more this fails.

I am using the smart mag theme in which i have enabled load more to fetch the posts for categories. But this query fails to show post in that particular orde. Is there any way to override the ajax to show the posts in my custom order on load more.

My function works well on pagination but fails on load more. So is there any way that to show the post in specific order even when the load more is on